# I can't change the keybinds in unity(specifically in the project settings)

Tags: unity-game-engine, key

so normally, it has text box and keys in it that are use to change the keys( like "Horizontal" or "Vertical"), but in my case, it just shows the keyword like "Negative Button" or "Positive Button" and more like, I have a picture down here that which is literally exactly what I am having right now [here's the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxRsR.png). Hope someone can help me(I have already upgrade unity to the latest LTS version).

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys, it seems like the problem is that there's a scrolling bar below it and i don't recognized it[I can do it now (:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjEKe.png)

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), this post doesn't actually provide an answer to your question.